# How to express array type in c# object

Tags: c#, asp.net, json

In my project, client send a json string back to server side. Below is parts of the json string.

```
"xy":[170,226],"cell":[["catalog_2","catalog_2"],["input_423","423"],["input_421","421"]]
```

On server side, I try to parse the json string into custom object. But I don't know which type can express the cell and xy property?

Please help, thanks.

Ps : I use JavaScriptSerializer to parse the json string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<int> xy { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> cell { get; set; }
}
```

It's a simply a list of ints, and then a list of list of strings. I don't think that's what you want, but that's unfortunately what you get due to how the JSON is structured. Perhaps "xy" should be a nested object and not an array? Do you have any control over the JSON?

By the way, I generated that object with [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

The `yx` property contains an array of `int` so you can use either `int[]` or `List<int>` the `cell` property is an array of arrays which are strings. Using the [JSON to C#](http://json2csharp.com) converter yields the following class:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public List<int> xy { get; set; }
    public List<List<string>> cell { get; set; }
}
```